# span tag on landroid tutorials

Tags: android, tags

I'm always seeing this kinds of lines on some of android tutorials that i found and i found it weird haha, can someone please explain me what are these tags, coz i really dont know what they mean?

[image]

[image]

```
<span class="n6o58" id="n6o58_2">public class</span> ExpandableListAdapter extends BaseExpandableListAdapter

<span class="n6o58" id="n6o58_2"> <----
```

Thank you have a good day :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All the  tags are not Java code but HTML.

My best guess is that the author of the tutorial uses a script to add syntax highlight to the java code they show, and the library somehow escapes the html tags, giving this result.

Obviously you should just ignore it, and maybe warn the author of the page that you see them.

Comment: Thats what i thought, i just needed someone expert to confirm it haha.Yesterday i tried to just take them out and it worked fine. Thank you brother. :)